# Determine control on which context menu was opened

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have a WinForm application with tekstbox controls that are connected to a ContextMenuStrip. If I rightclick on a textbox the context menu is (of course) opened. As far as I can see the ContextMenuStrip events don't give any info about the control on which the context menu was opened.

I can't use a work-around by looking at the focused control, as the rightclick doesn't give focus to the textbox (if it hasn't have focus before the rightclick).

So my question is: how can I determine the control on which the context menu was opened?

Comment: @Steve, yes that one answers my question. Didn't find that one myself. Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contextmenu has a [SourceControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.sourcecontrol.aspx) property which you should be able to use :)